# Debugger goes to return statement first

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I experience a strange behavior in X64 (debug mode) application during debugging with functions returning `std::string, std::stack, std::vector`:

```
std::stack<std::string> fooNoOk()
{
    std::stack<std::string> s;
    int r = 0;
    return s;
}

std::vector<int> barNook()
{
    std::vector<int> s;
    int r = 0;
    return s;
}

std::string bar2NoOk()
{
    std::string s;
    int r = 0;
    return s;
}

int foOk()
{
    int s{};
    int r = 0;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    fooNoOk();
    barNook();
    bar2NoOk();
    foOk();
}
```

for `fooNoOk, barNook` and `bar2NoOk` debugger as it enters function first jumps to the corresponding return statement, then goes through function and again to the return statement.
Here's disassembly listing of the application where it is clear that return statement is included twice (for example for `fooNoOk` function):

```
std::stack<std::string> fooNoOk()
{
00007FF63B544D30  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
00007FF63B544D35  push        rbp  
00007FF63B544D36  push        rdi  
00007FF63B544D37  sub         rsp,188h  
00007FF63B544D3E  lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
00007FF63B544D43  lea         rdi,[rsp+20h]  
00007FF63B544D48  mov         ecx,2Ah  
00007FF63B544D4D  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00007FF63B544D52  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF63B544D54  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+1A8h]  
00007FF63B544D5C  mov         dword ptr [rbp+144h],0  
00007FF63B544D66  lea         rcx,[__F9076511_TestReturn@cpp (07FF63B55906Ah)]  
00007FF63B544D6D  call        __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode (07FF63B54161Dh)  
    std::stack<std::string> s;
00007FF63B544D72  mov         edx,28h  
00007FF63B544D77  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+180h]  
00007FF63B544D7E  call        std::stack<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::__autoclassinit2 (07FF63B541280h)  
00007FF63B544D83  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+180h]  
00007FF63B544D8A  call        std::stack<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > >::stack<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > > > (07FF63B541532h)  
00007FF63B544D8F  mov         qword ptr [rbp+158h],rax  
    return s;
00007FF63B544D96  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+144h]  
00007FF63B544D9C  or          eax,1  
00007FF63B544D9F  mov         dword ptr [rbp+144h],eax  
    int r = 0;
00007FF63B544DA5  mov         dword ptr [r],0  
    return s;
00007FF63B544DAC  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+180h]  
}
```

the same is for `barNoOk` and `bar2NoOk`.
for `foOk` everything is Ok:

```
int foOk()
{
00007FF63B545500  push        rbp  
00007FF63B545502  push        rdi  
00007FF63B545503  sub         rsp,128h  
00007FF63B54550A  lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
00007FF63B54550F  lea         rcx,[__F9076511_TestReturn@cpp (07FF63B55906Ah)]  
00007FF63B545516  call        __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode (07FF63B54161Dh)  
    int s{};
00007FF63B54551B  mov         dword ptr [s],0  
    int r = 0;
00007FF63B545522  mov         dword ptr [r],0  
    return s;
00007FF63B545529  mov         eax,dword ptr [s]  
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/sK833bPav)

Comment: This might be because of NRVO

Comment: In debug mode, NRVO should not be applied though, should it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm I've never come across such a debugging experience over the past... 17 years

Comment: @Wintermute Not sure.  It probably shouldn't but bugs happen ;)

Comment: @amplifier I have but I've only experienced it on release builds which makes me think some sort of optimization might be happening.

Comment: Yeah, in release builds this sort of thing would be entirely unsurprising to me. Maybe check the project settings if some optimization is enabled by accident, otherwise I'm inclined to consider this a bug. Mind you, the asm doesn't look optimized, so it could be a hiccup in debug symbol generation.

Comment: @Wintermute optimization is disabled (/Od), explicit removing of pdb files everywhere didn't help.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://godbolt.org/z/sK833bPav there are also 2 return's.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. (VS 17.2.6+32630.192 VC++ 2022).

Comment: @amplifier That godbolt function only shows 1 `ret     0` per function.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, because there's only 1 "real" return, when debugger jumps to return statement second time.
Put mouse cursor over the 147-149 lines on the right pane and see the line 9 of the left pane correspondingly highlighted
Then put mouse cursor over the line 151 on the right pane and see again the line 9 of the left pane correspondingly highlighted

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of nrvo. There is `/Zc:nrvo` compiler option that enables it and is automatically set "when you compile using the /O2 option, the /permissive- option, or /std:c++20 or later", even in debug builds. So you have it enabled, beacuse you have `/permissive-` among compiler options.
You can disable it by adding `/Zc:nrvo-` to additional command line options.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-nrvo?view=msvc-170
The quote above is from this link.